# How to calculate correlation for every month between 2 dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, correlation

I have 2 year long time-series dataframes of the following structure, index is of date-time for both of them. I want to calculate the monthly correlation between `precip` and `rainfall_rate` columns, and then eventually plot the correlations month-wise.

I have tried `pd.corrwith()`. But I could not do it month-wise. Any suggestions would do (loops, predefined functions etc.)

```
# DATAFRAME #1

        latitude    longitude        precip
time            
2010-01-01  1.324997    103.674988  0.00000
2010-01-02  1.324997    103.674988  6.95574
2010-01-03  1.324997    103.674988  6.95574
2010-01-04  1.324997    103.674988  0.00000
2010-01-05  1.324997    103.674988  6.95574
.
.


# DATAFRAME #2
            rainfall_rate
timestamp   
2010-01-01  10.80
2010-01-02  0.12
2010-01-03  0.12
2010-01-04  7.92
2010-01-05  0.00
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resample`.

Note that calling `corr` produces some superfluous rows, which are then  eliminated by the `groupby` and `first` lines.

```
(
 df1.join(df2, how='left')
 .resample('1M')[['precip', 'rainfall_rate']]
 .corr()
 .groupby(level=0)
 .first()
 .rename(columns={'rainfall_rate': 'corr'})['corr']
)
```